# ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Font.color not avaliable in word 2013?

Tags: vba, ms-word

**ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Font.color** is not available updated version word.Then how to i give color without using colorindex.I want use RGB Color?

Comment: In Word 2016 it is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Font.Color` does work in Word 2013 - it would be surprising if it didn't considering the value Microsoft places on backwards compatibility.

For some odd reason, however, it's been classed as a "Hidden member" of the object model. Perhaps an oversight, or a mistake...

You can use it as in any other version of Word - it won't throw an error.

If you want to have it in IntelliSense, in the VBA Editor press F2 to open the Object Browser. Right-click in a pane and from the context menu select `Show Hidden Members`. `Color` will then appear in the object model lists "greyed out", but available.

Note that you'll probably have to do this in each session - the setting doesn't always stick. But once you know it's truly available that doesn't really matter...

Answer (score 0):

In Word 2016 the following works:

```
Sub TestMe()
    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Font.Color = RGB(12, 2, 3)
End Sub
```

Comment: ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Font.colorindex only i have. i am word 2013